Why is Mathematica using Re'[..] in calculation?
Suppose I have the following Mathematica code:
a[x_] := 1/Abs[E^Sqrt[f[x]]]

g[x_] = D[a[x], x]

The output of g[x] is $-\frac{e^{-\Re\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)} f'(x) \text{Re}'\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)}{2 \sqrt{f(x)}}$
I am not sure how to interpret this Re'[Sqrt[f[x]]]?
Suppose I take:
In[4]:= f[x_] := x^2

In[5]:= g[x]

Out[5]= -((E^-Re[Sqrt[x^2]] x Derivative[1][Re][Sqrt[x^2]])/Sqrt[x^2])

For g[2] I get $-\frac{\text{Re}'(2)}{e^2}$
How to help Mathematica give the correct Answer?

The notation is bad imo, but theres nothing wrong. Using the "chain rule" on f'Re'(f) yields exactly what you get per hand if you dont assume f to be real.

fyi, in V 14.1, e=Abs[Exp[x]];Assuming[Element[x,Reals],Simplify[D[e,x]]] gives E^x  Re'[x] same thing in Maple e:=abs(exp(x)); simplify(diff(e,x)) assuming real; gives just exp(x)  without Re'[x] part.  I am also not sure what Re'[x] is supposed to mean.  May be it means the derivative of the real part of x

Is there a way I can ignore it to get the same output as Maple for any general expression?

It is a nonsense. It is not clear to me why they decide to output meaningless expression like Re'[...], Re'[Sqrt[x^2]] /. x -> 3 // N returns Re'[3.], instead of throwing an error like  "do not use Abs inside D".

@azerbajdzan: Did you read my answer before having posted your ungrounded comment?

Related: Derivative of real functions including Re and Im, How to take a derivative of a function with a real part taken. Also, note that the conversion to Re occurs already at a[x], before any differentiation.

The correct result is obtained by
 a[x_] := 1/RealAbs[E^Sqrt[f[x]]];

g[x_] = D[a[x], x]


-((E^(2 Sqrt[f[x]]) Derivative[1][f][x])/( 2 Sqrt[f[x]] RealAbs[E^Sqrt[f[x]]]^3))

Then
f[x_]:=x^2; g[2]


-(1/E^2)

As the documentation (see Properties&Realations) clearly says Abs[x] is not a differentiable function.

@The down-voter: What is incorrect in my answer? It is unfair to down vote without any explaining comment.

I am not sure why someone downvoted it. (+1) from my side. Just a quick follow-up query: what if the function gives a complex valued answer?

@codebpr: RealAbs assumes its argument is real-valued and, for example, RealAbs[1 + I] returns the input.
